# How to modify mediaWiki, create article form?

Tags: php, mediawiki

i need to modify the create article form in mediaWiki

basically i need to just add a title field there, because mediaWiki doesn't allow a title to be chosen when the article is being created while i want to add that functionality, i found that there is a file named "EditPage.php" where a function named "showEditForm" is located but in this function there is no place where i could change the whole html of the edit form. someone please help.

Comment: There isn't any Software Development element in the question.

Comment: well this question was intended to those who are very familiar with mediaWiki codebase, i always find it hard to explain mediaWiki related questions to the users here unfortunately :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue, i had to modify

```
showFormBeforeText
```

function, i added a text field there and it worked!.